# Text value not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I'm new to KnockOut. I've followed along the tutorial on there site and I'm now trying to use that knowledge in my project for school.

Unfortunately I'm stuck. I want to dynamically fill my text from a local JSON file. 
I have debugged and my code for fetching the data works, but doesn't show on my HTML page.

A piece of my View:

```
<p data-bind="text: level.assignment">
   replace dynamically
</p>
```

KnockOut is connected to my HTML because other bindings work.
My ViewModel

```
//Class to represent the Level
function Level(id, assignment, videoURL) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
    self.assignment = assignment;
    self.videoURL = videoURL;
}

function LevelViewModel(id) {
    //Data
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
    self.level = ko.computed(function () {
        //fetching the local json
        $.get('/Data/Text2Speech.json', "", function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (textStatus != "success") {
                return "not found";
            }
            //Make the level object
            self.level = new Level(data.exercise[self.id - 1].id, data.exercise[self.id - 1].assignment, data.exercise[self.id - 1].videoURL);
            return self.level;
        });
    }, this);
};
```

The debugging window.

[image: Debugging Window In Chrome]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

My JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pPZ48/

Comment: I would love a working jsFiddle :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<p data-bind="text: level().assignment">replace dynamically</p>
```

instead of

```
<p data-bind="text: level.assignment">replace dynamically</p>
```

Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L3TNq/)**

Comment: @TimRijckaert have you checked fiddle

Comment: Yes I did I can't see what I'm doing different. Here is mine: http://jsfiddle.net/pPZ48/

Comment: your code contains error you havn't removed jquery get method clousre  `});` so that you will get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , ` check ur browser console

Comment: That seems to work, however, what is wrong with my initial code then? I'm just fetching some JSON and the debugger shows that it's fetching it properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54383/discussion-between-aneesh-a-e-and-tim-rijckaert).

Answer (score 1):

The solution was found by Aneesh A.E.
He saw that the $.get() function from JQuery was Async.
So here is the correct code:

```
//Class to represent the Level
function Level(id, assignment, videoURL) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
    self.assignment = assignment;
    self.videoURL = videoURL;
}

function getRemoteFile() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Data/Text2Speech.json',
        async: false,
        success: function () {
            console.log("Success");
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Error");
        }
    }).responseText;
}

function LevelViewModel(id) {
    //Data
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
    self.level = ko.computed(function () {
        //fetching the local json
        data = JSON.parse(getRemoteFile());
        self.level = new Level(data.exercise[self.id - 1].id, data.exercise[self.id - 1].assignment, data.exercise[self.id - 1].videoURL);
        return self.level;
    }, this);
};
```

As well as changing the HTML to

```
<p data-bind="text: level().assignment">
 replace dynamically
</p>
```